# Why is it natural to define reflections in terms of its hyperplane?

Tags: geometry, reflection, convention, geometric-algebras

There are two ways to reflect a vector $v$ by another vector $u$. The first is to 'directly' reflect $v$ through $u$:

[image]

where $v'=2P_uv-v$ with $P_u=\frac{uu^T}{|u|^2}$. The second way is to reflect $v$ through the normal plane spanned by $u$ like this:

[image]

This time the reflection is $-1$ times the other convention i.e. $v'=v-2P_uv$. To me the first way seems more intuitive but if I look at this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra#Reflection they use the second convention. Is it common in math to use the second convention? Are there any benefits compared to the first convention?

Comment: I find it more natural to think that a reflection in an $n$-dimensional space leaves an $(n-1)$-dimensional (affine) subspace fixed pointwise. After all, in our $n=3$ world mirrors are 2-dimensional rather than 1-dimensional. Admittedly I may be biased having spent a bit of time studying Coxeter groups.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Good point when you mention mirrors. The second convention generalizes better when your objects don't neatly sit at the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection typically means “I have an eigenspace for 1 with dimension $n-1$ and an eigenspace for $-1$ of dimension 1”.  The former eigenspace is the hyperplane, the latter is the subspace spanned by the  normal.

It seems to me the reason you think the two are similar is compounded by the fact your example is in  2-d.

The first example you are giving is “reflecting through a line.”  This works in 2 dimensions, but in $n$ dimensions, if you reflect all vector across a fixed vector in the plane they generate, you can get something else, namely a rotation.  I hesitate to call this a reflection but as it happen some authors (see last big paragraph [of the lede](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)) ) are willing to admit any nonidentity involutive isometry with an affine eigenspace for 1, of dimension less than $n$ as a reflection.

The choice of thinking in terms of the hyper plane or its  normal are both still there in $n$ dimensions, but the different “nature” of each type is a little more obvious.  Each one has the data needed to determine the other one. This is a duality.  But they are only both lines in 2-d.

Comment: Ok so the second convention is preferred because reflections are defined in terms of hyperplanes, if you can call the first one a convention at all. I guess the first method still works in $n$ dimensions but this answers my question.

Comment: The OP's first geometric construction for reflecting through a line makes perfect sense in any number of dimensions and is analogous to the well-known notion of reflection through a point. To say "reflection always occur in hyperplanes" is an oversimplification: I agree that "reflection" without any further qualification generally means a reflection that fixes a hyperplane, but the term is used for more general involutions as well. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics).

Comment: @RobArthan what notion of “reflection through a line” in say 3-d do you have in mind?

Comment: Drop a perpendicular from $v$ to the line $l$ (which passes through the origin), say meeting it at $w$ and then continue it for a distance $\|v - w\|$ along the perpendicular (so $v' = v + 2(w - v)$). So this looks like reflection in the origin if you look down on it along $l$ and is just like the OP's first figure.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree that the assignment you are describing is a reflection in the plane formed by the vector and line. Though, I'd interpret "reflection in 3-d dimensions" to be a reflection on all of $\mathbb R^3$.  The assignment you're describing, applied to all vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ is probably better called a rotation.

Comment: Sure it's a rotation in $\Bbb{R}^3$, just like reflection in the origin is a rotation in $\Bbb{R}^2$. In $\Bbb{R}^4$, it's not a rotation, just like reflection in the origin is not a rotation in $\Bbb{R}^3$. As the Wikipedia article I referred to says, the term "reflection" is used for a wider class of involutions than reflections in a hyperplane. All I am objecting to here is your statement that "reflections always occur in hyperplanes" which needs some qualification.

Comment: @RobArthan point taken: I dialed back the assertion.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Sorry to be so pernickety, but I quite like reflections through the origin etc.

Comment: @RobArthan Some call all length preserving linear transformations of $\Bbb{R}^n$ *rotations*, and may further call those that don't preserve handedness ($\det=-1$) *improper rotations* (IIRC). While I, too, do remember that the 180 degree rotation of the plane was called *a reflection w.r.t. a point* in hhigh school geometry, the time since high school has left me strongly feeling that a reflection always reverses handedness.

Answer (score 0):

The geometric algebra reflection expression is based on the following illustration
[image: projection and rejection with reflection]

Observe that the projection of $ \mathbf{v} $ along the direction $ \hat{\mathbf{u}} $ (assumed to be a unit vector for simplicity) is
$$(\hat{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \mathbf{v}) \hat{\mathbf{u}},$$
and the component of $ \mathbf{v} $ perpendicular to $ \hat{\mathbf{u}} $ (the rejection) is:
$$\mathbf{v} - (\hat{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \mathbf{v}) \hat{\mathbf{u}}.$$

From the diagram, it is clear that the reflection is just
$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{v}' &= \mathbf{v} - 2 \left( { \mathbf{v} - (\hat{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \mathbf{v}) \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right)  \\ &= 2 (\hat{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \mathbf{v}) \hat{\mathbf{u}} - \mathbf{v}.\end{aligned}$$

There is no use of geometric algebra in this.  A geometric algebra is a vector space where the elements of the space are products of vectors, subject to an additional ``contraction identity'' $\mathbf{x}^2 = \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x}$.
One can form various special product combinations that have useful applications.  In particular, it can be shown that a symmetric sum is related to the dot product
$$\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = \frac{1}{{2}} \left( { \mathbf{x} \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{y} \mathbf{x} } \right).$$
We can also form an antisymmetric sum
$$\mathbf{x} \wedge \mathbf{y} = \frac{1}{{2}} \left( { \mathbf{x} \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y} \mathbf{x} } \right),$$
where we call $ \wedge $ the wedge operator, an operator that happens to be related to the cross product in 3D.
The concepts above can be used to decompose a vector into projective and rejective components as follows
$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{v}&= \mathbf{v} \hat{\mathbf{u}} \hat{\mathbf{u}} \\ &= \left( { \mathbf{v} \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} \\ &= \left( { \mathbf{v} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{u}} + \mathbf{v} \wedge \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} \\ &= \left( { \mathbf{v} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} + \left( { \mathbf{v} \wedge \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}}.\end{aligned}$$
The first term we recognize as the projection, allowing us to identify the remainder as the rejection.  It's also straightforward to show that
$$\left( { \left( { \mathbf{v} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \cdot \left( { \left( { \mathbf{v} \wedge \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) = 0,$$
satisfying our expections for the projection and rejection.

We can utilize this to compute the reflection, which is
$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{v}'&= \mathbf{v} - 2 \left( { \mathbf{v} \wedge \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} \\ &= \mathbf{v} \hat{\mathbf{u}} \hat{\mathbf{u}} - 2 \left( { \mathbf{v} \wedge \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} \\ &= \left( { \mathbf{v} \hat{\mathbf{u}} - 2 \left( { \mathbf{v} \wedge \hat{\mathbf{u}} } \right) } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} \\ &= \left( { \mathbf{v} \hat{\mathbf{u}} - \left( { \mathbf{v} \hat{\mathbf{u}} - \hat{\mathbf{u}} \mathbf{v} } \right) } \right) \hat{\mathbf{u}} \\ &= \hat{\mathbf{u}} \mathbf{v} \hat{\mathbf{u}}.\end{aligned}$$
This sandwich of $ \mathbf{v} $ between $ \hat{\mathbf{u}} $ is the usual way that reflection is expressed in geometric algebra.  As for benefits, this approach leads to the sandwich reflection identity above, which is probably about as simple as a reflection can be expressed.